# Problem in getting stringValue from NSSecureTextField

Tags: cocoa, css-selectors, nstextfield

I have a password field of type `NSSecureTextField` say `passwordField` and a `NSButton`. I have assigned return key as key equivalent for the button action triggering. After pressing the button I get user entered text as `[passwordField stringValue]` this will give the correct value only, when user press return key after entering his password but not when user clicks on the button through mouse. In the latter case it will give nil value. I have tried hard to find the problem but no use. If anybody knows what is going wrong, please help me.

Regards
ypk

**EDIT:** This is observed only in 10.5 and works fine on 10.6.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking ***Continuous*** on the text field in Interface Builder.
Also make sure ***Action*** is set as ***Sent On End Editing***.

[image: ib settings]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Though I have changed the state to **Continuous** no use. From beginning only action is sent on End Editing.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem. For me, it turned out that the focus was not correctly set on the text field. Calling `[window makeFirstResponder: textfield]` after a timeout of 0.5 seconds solved it.

Comment: It works! if the NSSecureTextField don't have the focus always return a wrong string

Answer (score 0):

I usually explicitly call `[window makeFirstResponder:nil` as one of the first lines in my button click events to ensure the `Sent On End Editing` event is called.